# How to iterate through multiple directories with multiple ifs in bash?

Tags: bash, directory, conditional-statements, file-exists

unfortunately I'm quite new at bash, and I want to write a script that will start in a main directory, and check all subdirectories one by one for the presence of certain files, and if those files are present, perform an operation on them. For now, I have written a simplified version to test whether I can do the first part (checking for the files in each directory). This code runs without any errors that I can tell, but it does not echo anything to say that it has successfully found the files which I know are there.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    runlist=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
    for f in *; do
        if [[ -d {$f} ]]; then
        #if f is a directory then cd into it
            cd "{$f}"
            for b in $runlist; do
                if [[ -e "{$b}.png" ]]; then
                    echo "Found {$b}"
                #if the file exists then say so
                fi
            done
            cd - 
        fi
    done
```

'''

Comment: Use the `find` command to search a hierarchy recursively, don't do it yousefl.

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net to verify your script.  `{$b}` does not look good, maybe you want `${b}` and `${f}`

Comment: I need to do more than just find it eventually, this is a simplified version of the script which I will add to once it works. The find command will not do everything I need.

Comment: Thanks Jetchisel, that seems to have helped.

Comment: You can start the loop with: `for f in */; do ...; done` since the `*/` will expand to directories so you don't have to do the test if it is a directory. Also `cd "$f" || exit` to exit the script immediately if cd fails and not continue. As what @Barmar said about the using `find`, You can invoke a shell using `-exec` and do the other things, or use `globstar` to be recursive.

Comment: Also you need to do `"${runlist[@]}"` to expand it as an array and not just a single first element, `"$runlist"` is the same as `"${runlist[0]}"`

Comment: Thank you! I made the first and last changes you suggested and it's working great now. The reason I use the test for the directory rather than just search for "*/" is to make it easier to add in an error message echo later. Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI for your next question provide a [mcve].  Without sample input, desired output and current output it is arder to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

The following will do the trick (a combination of find, array, and if then else):

```
# list of files we are looking for
runlist=(1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128)

#find each of above anywhere below current directory
# using -maxdepth 1 because, based on on your exam you want to look one level only
# if that's not what you want then take out -maxdepth 1 from the find command
for b in ${runlist[@]}; do
   echo
   PATH_TO_FOUND_FILE=`find . -name $b.png`
   if [ -z "$PATH_TO_FOUND_FILE" ]
   then
      echo "nothing found" >> /dev/null
   else
      # You wanted a postive confirmation, so
      echo found $b.png
      # Now do something with the found file. Let's say ls -l: change that to whatever
      ls -l $PATH_TO_FOUND_FILE
   fi
done
```

Here is an example run:

```
mamuns-mac:stack foo$ ls -lR
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  4 foo  1951595366  128 Apr 11 18:03 dir1
drwxr-xr-x  3 foo  1951595366   96 Apr 11 18:03 dir2
-rwxr--r--  1 foo  1951595366  652 Apr 11 18:15 find_file_and_do_something.sh

./dir1:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  1951595366  0 Apr 11 17:58 1.png
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  1951595366  0 Apr 11 17:58 8.png

./dir2:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  1951595366  0 Apr 11 18:03 64.png
mamuns-mac:stack foo$ ./find_file_and_do_something.sh 

found 1.png
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  1951595366  0 Apr 11 17:58 ./dir1/1.png



found 8.png
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  1951595366  0 Apr 11 17:58 ./dir1/8.png



found 64.png
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  1951595366  0 Apr 11 18:03 ./dir2/64.png
```